# Fill in daily load profiles with energy to fill troughs

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to fill daily load profiles with a given amount of energy for each day such that the energy is added to the lowest points (the troughs) - in effect raising the minimum values.

Let's say x is a simplified data frame for 3 days, each day has 4 hours and corresponding values and I want to add a total of 4, 5 and 3 units to each of the 3 days respectively.

Here is the data frame where x$day specifies the day, x$hour specifies the hour, x$daytime specifies the timestamp, x$value specifies the value and x$final_value contains what the final values should be.

```
x <- data.frame(day = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), hour = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                daytime = c(1.0,1.25,1.5,1.75,2.0,2.25,2.5,2.75,3.0,3.25,3.5,3.75),
                value = c(7,3,6,2, 8,3,3,5, 4,1,9,3), final_value = c(7,4.5,6,4.5, 8,5.333,5.333,5.333, 4,3.5,9,3.5))
```

Visually, I am filling in the troughs of the red curve to the blue curve level.

```
ggplot2::ggplot(x) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(aes(x=daytime,y=value), colour = 'red') +
  ggplot2::geom_line(aes(x=daytime,y=final_value), colour = 'blue')
```

I am after an efficient way to do this without using for loops.  I was thinking of using dplyr::group_by(day) but a few ideas I have had have resulted in dead ends.

I would be very grateful if someone could assist.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: I made them up as an example.  There is nothing special about them.  They will come from another process.

Comment: As I said, the values will come from another process so they won't be completely arbitrary.  This is a simplified example to demonstrate what I wish to achieve.

Comment: I want to fill up the troughs - the minimum values.  I don't want to create new maximums.

Comment: I can’t think of an obvious way without loops. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you want. You will have a daily 'final_value', and you want to 'distribute' the diff between 'final_value' and 'value' between the hourly 'lowest points'. How do you decide which are the 'lowest points'? In day 1 you decided to have two lower points, in day 2 there are three. What is the process?

Comment: The lowest points have the lowest magnitude in the value column.